# Load a private Drive Presentation in ifram using url, however same thing is not working for PDF

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api

I am able to load a private Google Drive Presentation ifram using url, fileid & accesstoken ,
however same thing is not working for PDF.

**fileId** : 13zxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-

**accessToken** : ya29.xxxx-xxxx

**(1) Working : private Google Drive Presentation**

```
var  googleDrivefileUrl1 = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/"+fileId+"/embed?rm=minimal&access_token="+**accessToken**
var iframe1  = $('<iframe src="'+googleDrivefileUrl1+'" style="width: 90%; height: 100px">');
$('#previewDiv1').append(testIFrame1);
```

**(2) Not Working: private Google Drive PDF**

```
var  googleDrivefileUrl2 = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/"+fileId+"/embed?rm=minimal&access_token="+accessToken
var iframe2  = $('<iframe src="'+googleDrivefileUrl2+'" style="width: 90%; height: 100px">');
$('#previewDiv2').append(testIFrame2);
```

Is Google only support presentation, and not supported for PDF ?

Or am I doing some mistake ?

I will highly appreciate help & guidance.

Answer (score 0):

### It is possible to embed PDF files on your Google Drive into iframes, you just need to do it differently

The `googleDrivefileUrl` should be of the form

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/preview`

- Note that `https://docs.google.com` is only valid for Google documents like Google Sheets, Google Docs etc.
- For other documents on your drive, the URL begins with `https://drive.google.com`
- You can also obtain the embed URL by:

  - Opening the pdf file on your Google Drive as preview
  - Click on the "three dots" and `Open in new window`
  - Click again on the "three dots" and `Embed item...`
  - This will direclty give you the correct emebdding code syntax

Comment: For PDF : I have try this way, it is working when file has public access. However this is not working when file has domain or private level access.

Comment: This is intended behavior, if you want a workaround - embed the file into an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) an deploy it as "Execute the web app as:  `you`" and "Who has access to the app: Anyone" . Then, embed the WeBapp into your Apps Script. Doing so you make only the WebApp but not the PDF itself public.